# Get input character position in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, angular, contenteditable

I have a contenteditale div in my Angular 6 project

```
<div contenteditable="true" (input)="checkContent($event)"></div>
```

When user types a character, I would like to get the position of the character.

What I'm actualy trying to do is to check if there is a '@' before the input character and If yes then count characters between '@' and input character

Examples(considering the Uppercase character is the last entered):

```
hellO // postion = 4
hello World // postion = 6
Hello world // postion = 0
```

For now I can get the entered character from the component with event.data

```
checkContent(event: any){
    console.log(event.data);
}
```

How can I get the position of the last entered character ?

Comment: Can you clarify one thing, once any character is entered from where you have to match the position ? I mean which string or content ?

Comment: What is your actual use case?

Comment: @ngChaitanya from the contenteditable first character

Comment: @charlietfl I just want the input character position as described in example

Comment: But that may not be trivial depending on what you are trying to accomplish. Without more background there is no simple answer or answers may not meet your needs. You mentioning typing, but what about pasting for example? Or corrections user makes ? A proper explanation of the higher level problem you are trying to solve would help

Comment: @charlietfl okay in fact when a user enter a character, I would like to check if there is a '@' character before and if yes count characters between the input character and the '@' character

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the question. please check

Comment: For what purpose? Last character entered may not be the last character in the string....consider corrections for example and pasting. Providing limited details for a non trivial problem isn't helping. This may also be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @charlietfl yes I have to consider correction. Example there is two words("hello world") in the div and user types a character between these two words("hello E world"), position will be = 6. Hope you understand

Comment: No... you keep asking about position but not explaining why that position is important and what you need it for exactly. Perhaps all you need is a regex. Explain your use case in full detail, we shouldn't have to try to guess

Comment: @charlietfl I need this position for checking existence of a '@' character before and If yes then count number of characters between that '@' character and the character that user just input

Comment: That simply does not explain WHY? What if I start with `@abaaa` and change to `@baaaa`. What would position 1 or 2 tell you if the whole sequence is much longer? Wouldn't a regex do what you need? Why is it so difficult to explain the higher level use case?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `keydown` and `keyup` event to get the difference between 2 strings, then you will find exactly the index of last character.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, then this works...

1 - Insert a temporary span (with an id) at the cursor position that contains a character you will never type (I use hex 7F).

2 - Get the textContent (innerText) of your div into a Variable.

3 - Delete the temporary span.

4 - Use Variable.search(/\x7F/) (in my example) to get position of current character.

Comment: can you please give me an example sir ?

Comment: Frankly, no, I'm not going to write your script for you - which part of this are you struggling with?